# Font-Awesome show square instead icon

Tags: java, font-awesome, omnifaces

I have a WAR file that depends on a JAR file, called **fr-web.jar**. This jar contains all css, plugins and templates to render my HTML page.

Inside my jar file i have a XHTML page that import font-awesome, see:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="third/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>
```

But in my page this don't work, font-awesome render Squares. If i change to MAXCDN link everything works, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Obs: I'm using omnifaces 2.6 to resolve this resources and have it mapped in faces-config.xml:

```
 <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>pt_BR</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
    </application>
```

**EDIT 1:**

I found the problem , maven filtering is causing the problem, see:

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

If i remove the "filtering" everything works. But why ?